# Cascade rows below header rows in a table

Tags: html, html-table

I've created a table for a website that has rows underneath headings. There are going to be multiple headers and I want the table to only show the headers when first displayed, and to display the below rows only when a button by the header is clicked. Is there any way of doing this? I've been looking up cascading tables but those have only shown drop-down menus, which isn't what I'm looking for. Any help (links, explanations, code) would be greatly appreciated! Below is an example of one of the headings and some of the following rows in my table.

To further clarify with this example, what I'd want to do is make it so that only the row displaying "Current Location" is shown and the following rows (rural, suburban, metropolitan--types of locations) are not visible until Current Location is clicked or a button there is clicked.

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="5%">
        <tr><th align=left>Current Location</th></tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Rural</td>
            <td>Total Value</td>
            <td>Average Value</td>
            <td>Percentage of total</td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Suburban</td>
            <<td>Total Value</td>
            <td>Average Value</td>
            <td>Percentage of total</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Metropolitan</td>
            <td>Total Value</td>
            <td>Average Value</td>
            <td>Percentage of total</td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: You can set the `display` attribute via CSS. If the button is clicked, `display: block;`, otherwise `display: none;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given similar HTML to the above (note that I've added `colspan` attributes, and removed the in-line, and deprecated, attributes):

```
<table>
    <tbody class="header">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4"><a href="#demo">Current Location</a>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody id="demo">
        <tr>
            <td>Rural</td>
            <td>Total Value</td>
            <td>Average Value</td>
            <td>Percentage of total</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Suburban</td>
            <td>Total Value</td>
            <td>Average Value</td>
            <td>Percentage of total</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Metropolitan</td>
            <td>Total Value</td>
            <td>Average Value</td>
            <td>Percentage of total</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody class="header">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4"><a href="#demo2">Another Location</a>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody id="demo2">
        <tr>
            <td>Rural</td>
            <td>Total Value</td>
            <td>Average Value</td>
            <td>Percentage of total</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Suburban</td>
            <td>Total Value</td>
            <td>Average Value</td>
            <td>Percentage of total</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Metropolitan</td>
            <td>Total Value</td>
            <td>Average Value</td>
            <td>Percentage of total</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The following CSS works (tested only in Chromium 27):

```
table, td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
td {
    padding: 5px;
}
/* hides *all* 'tbody' elements:
*/
tbody {
    display: none;
}
/* shows the 'tbody.header' elements:
*/
tbody.header {
    display: table-row-group;
}
/* shows the relevant elements (in those browsers that support ':target'):
*/
tbody:target {
    display: table-row-group;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/URDQd/).

The above relies on `tbody` elements, with an `id`, being used to group content together and the link, in the header-row, linking to that `id`.

Unfortunately, I'm unable to think of any other non-JavaScript alternative to implement what you seem to want; so while this does have compatibility problems, it really is the best I can think of under the constraints of the [html](/questions/tagged/html) tag you've specified.